# Help with Taylor series for proving the approximation of a function

Tags: proof-explanation, taylor-expansion, approximation, binomial-theorem

Recently I got the following question:

If $a$ and $b$ are nearly equal, show that $$\left(\frac{5a-2b}{3b}\right)^{\frac13} \approx \frac a{a+2b} + \frac{b+a}{3b}.$$

I have attempted to solve this using a Taylor series:
$$
\frac{5a-2b}{3b} = x\\
\text{Taylor series around $x=1$:}\\
f(1) = 1\\
f'(1) = \frac13\\
f(x) \approx 1 + \frac13(x-1)+...\\
\text{Substituting }\frac{5a-2b}{3b} = x,\\
f(a) \approx \frac{5a+4b}{9b} \approx \frac{b+2a}{9b}+\frac{b+a}{3b}
$$
This is where I have reached so far, my lecturer hasn't covered or even talked about Taylor series and I have tried to understand it on my own. I think the last part might have a problem, although I'm not sure exactly.

I also think this could be done using binomial expansion, but I'm not sure how to go around it.

Any help or advice is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Your derivation looks sensible to me. If $a\approx b$, then $a/(a+2b)\approx (b+2a)/9b$ . To first order, those terms are the same. It might help to write $a=b+\epsilon$ to quantify $a\approx b$. You should be able to show that to the order $O(\epsilon)$, both expressions are identical, and that they differ only in $O(\epsilon^2)$.

Comment: Note that unless you expand your $\approx$ identities in terms of powers of $\epsilon$, their representations are not unique.

Comment: @DominikS I've never come across $O(\epsilon^2)$ before, how would I expand the identities using it?

Comment: If you write $a = b + \epsilon$, then your expression will depend on $b$ and $\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is "small" (i.e. close to zero). Then you expand the expression in terms of powers of $\epsilon$ (which would be the Taylor series wrt $\epsilon$ around zero). Two expressions are identical up to $O(\epsilon^2)$ means that their expansions only differ in the terms $\epsilon^n$ for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: I will try to clarify in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivation looks correct, what remains to show is that for $a\approx b$ we have $\frac a{a+2b}\approx \frac{b+2a}{9b}$.

**What do we mean by $\approx$ for two functions?**
In terms of comparing two functions: It depends on the context, but here one might argue that $f(x)\approx g(x)$ near $x=x_0$ means that $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$ and $f'(x_0) = g'(x_0)$ (i.e. same value and same tangent). One would write that $f(x) - g(x) = O((x-x_0)^2)$, which means that the corresponding Taylor series match on the first 2 terms, but might differ on the higher-order terms.

You wouldn't say that $f(x)\approx g(x)$ if $f'(x_0) \neq g'(x_0)$. In this case, the Taylor series of the functions would only match on the first (zero order) term.

**Application to your expressions.**
To make this rigorous, write $a = b + \epsilon$, with $\epsilon$ "small" (to express $a\approx b$). We take the difference of the two terms we need to compare, and substitute $a$:
$$\frac a{a+2b}- \frac{b+2a}{9b} = \frac{-2\epsilon^2}{9b(3b+\epsilon)} = \frac{-2}{27b^2}\epsilon^2 + O(\epsilon^3).\qquad (*)$$
You can justify the last identity by using the Taylor expansion of $1/(3b+\epsilon)$ around $\epsilon = 0$:
$$\frac 1{3b+\epsilon} = \frac1{3b} - \frac1{9b^2}\epsilon +O(\epsilon^2).$$
When we multiply this by $\frac{-2\epsilon^2}{9b}$, we find (again, order by powers of $\epsilon$):
$$\frac{-2\epsilon^2}{9b(3b+\epsilon)} = \frac{-2}{27b^2}\epsilon^2 +  \frac{2}{81b^3}\epsilon^3 + (\epsilon^4) = \frac{-2}{27b^2}\epsilon^2 + O(\epsilon^3).$$
The $O(\epsilon^3)$-notation in $(*)$ encapsulates any remaining higher-order terms of the form $c_3\epsilon^3 + c_4\epsilon^4 +\cdots$, containing no smaller powers of $\epsilon$.

This is as good as it can get if you use the first order Taylor expansion. "To first order", your solution is just as valid as the expression in the problem statement. If you would want higher accuracy, you would need more terms in the expansion of $\sqrt[3]{\cdot}$.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation for further explanation on the notation.

Comment: I think I understand, what I'm still unsure of is how you brought out $O(\epsilon^3)$ from the difference of the two equations.

Comment: Right - I have added an explanation, I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: Not really, I don't know if there's a gap in my knowledge on this. I still don't see how $\frac{-2 \epsilon^2}{9b(3b+\epsilon)} = \frac{-2\epsilon^2}{25b^2}+O(\epsilon^3}$

Comment: Is it better now? If not: Is the issue about finding the Taylor expansion?

Comment: It makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=k b$ which makes the lhs to be
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{3} (5 k-2) }$$ Use the binomial expansion or Taylor series around $k=1$
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{3} (5 k-2) }=1+\frac{5 (k-1)}{9}-\frac{25}{81} (k-1)^2+O\left((k-1)^3\right)$$

The rhs write
$$\frac{k+1}{3}+\frac{k}{k+2}=1+\frac{5 (k-1)}{9}-\frac{2}{27} (k-1)^2+O\left((k-1)^3\right)$$

They are not the same but
$$\text{lhs - rhs}=-\frac{19}{81} (k-1)^2+O\left((k-1)^3\right)$$ which is not much since $k\approx 1$

Comment: A small comment: Especially in the context of Taylor and/or asymptotic expansions, the expansion is usually performed in terms of the *difference* and not the *ratio* of the relevant quantities. One reason is that the former is agnostic to the size of $b$, whereas $k = a/b$ will be very sensitive to small $b$. Of course, both approaches are equivalent, but the latter is quite uncommon in my personal experience.